# Jquery Add div inside h1 tag

Tags: jquery, html

Using jquery, How would I wrap a div class around the text inside all h1 tags. E.g to make all

`<h1> test </h1>`

in a document into

`<h1> <div class="wrap">test </div></h1>`.

I am having a mental block. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Better wrap a `<span>` instead of a DIV.

Comment: I an trying to achieve using jquery, Wrapping a div inside the h1 tag around the text content

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use use `$('h1').wrapInner('<div class="wrap" />');`

But use a `<span class="wrap" />`

#### *[Demo jsBin](http://jsbin.com/ixaqic/edit#javascript,html,live)*

From the DOCS: http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/

Comment: Amazing, you are right I will use span instead. Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 6):

`<div>` is not valid inside of `<h1>`. You would be better off using a `<span>`. Pure JavaScript:

```
var h = document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0],
    d = document.createElement('span');
while(h.firstChild) d.appendChild(h.firstChild);
h.appendChild(d);
d.className = "wrap";
```

But that said, can't you just apply the "wrap" class to the `<h1>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Get and wrap the content from the h1
var content = $('h1').html();
content = '<div class="wrap">' + content + '</div>';

// Reinsert the content into the h1
$('h1').html( content );
```

This can of course be done in a single line, but this made it a bit more clear.